# Fullcalendar Stay on the same date after refreshing

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want that my calendar stays on the same month, week or day after refreshing i got it to work with the view but not with the date.
I have been trying to solve this problem. i even got it to work with.

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultStartDate", view.start);
localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultView", view.name);
}
defaultDate: (localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultStartDate") !== null ?  localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultStartDate") : moment()),
defaultView: (localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultView") !== null ? localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultView") : "agendaDay"),
```

the problem with this code is that on the view "month" it skips on month back after refreshing.
Can some one please help me with this?

Comment: Look at it another way, is there a way you could avoid needing to refresh the page in the first place?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I also had that idea. The problem is i have a select option to select a student to add to the Calendar for that it needs to be refreshed after a student has been selected. The second problem is i need to show an error message if there has been some wrong input to the calendar with php. for that it also needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Both of those things could be done using AJAX, thus avoiding the need for a full refresh.